# I keep getting "Unable to index into an object of type System.String." when I change the value of my array in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am trying to create a PowerShell script that creates folders (nested and multiple). I managed to get the nested folders to work, and I am pretty new to this, but I cant seem to get the multiple folders to work. I basically want to make a string array with each item being a user inputted string. I tried everything but it just doesn't seem to work.

Here's my code

```
echo "Folder Creator for FS2019 by Skaytacium, enter the values for unlimited nested folders! Remember though, 260 characters is the max nesting limit!"

$count = Read-Host -Prompt 'How many folders? Value'
$count = [int16]$count

$sub = Read-Host -Prompt 'Do you wanna nest? 2/1'

$namestring = "./"
$storay

[string]$array = "0", "0", "0"

$arac = 0
$arac = [int16]$arac


if ($sub -eq "2") {
    echo "The specified folders will be nested"

    while ($count -gt 0) {

        $namestring = $namestring + (Read-Host -Prompt 'Name') + "/"
        $count--
        echo $namestring

        if ($count -eq 0) {
            md $namestring
        }
    }
}

elseif ($sub -eq "1") {
    echo "The specified folders will be consecutive (in the same dir)"

    while ($count -gt 0){
        $storay = Read-Host "Name"
        $array[1] = @("please help")
        echo $array
        $arac++
        $count--
    }
}

Pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
[string] $array = "0", "0", "0"  # !! creates *single* string
```

with:

```
[string[]] $array = "0", "0", "0"  # creates *array* of strings
```

In your original command, the `[string]` type constraint to the left of the variable caused the input array (which is implicitly of type `[object[]]`) to be converted to a *single string* (`[string]`) with contents `0 0 0` 
(PowerShell stringifies arrays by concatenating their elements with separator `$OFS`, which defaults to a space.)
By contrast, `[string[]]` results in an *array*, whose *elements* are `string`-typed.

A `[...]`-enclosed literal in PowerShell refers to a .NET type. It is called a ***type literal***.

- If you place such a type literal to the *left* of variable assignment, you ***type-constrain*** that variable, meaning that it can only store values that are instances of that type, and that it automatically tries to *convert* instances of other types to that type, if possible; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58936005/45375) for more information about type constraints.
- You can also use a type literal to ***cast*** expressions to that type (as your code does in statement `$arac = [int16] $arac`), which also means converting the operand to that type, as a one-time operation.

In type literal `[string[]]`, the `[]` after the type name, `string`, specifies an *array* of elements of that type; except for the enclosing `[...]`, this **notation** is the same as the one used by the .NET [`Type.GetType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype#System_Type_GetType_System_String_) method; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57246523/45375) for more information.

Note that **PowerShell's type conversions are much more flexible than C#'s** for instance; they are augmented by built-in conversion rules and attempts to automatically use appropriate *constructors* and static `.Parse()` methods.

---

Note that **you don't strictly need the type constraint** `[string[]]`, except if you want to make sure that assigning to elements of this array later automatically performs to-string conversion.

```
# OK, but creates [object[]] array that now happens to contain [string]
# instances, but the type of the elements isn't locked in.
$array = "0", "0", "0"
```

---

As for **the specific error message you saw**:

Because `$array` was just a single `[string]` in your code, indexing with, say, `[0]` indexes in the string's *character array*.

Technically, this works for *getting* characters from the array, but you cannot *set* them:

```
# GET the 1st character from the string stored in $var
PS> $var = 'foo'; $var[0]
f     # 1st character in the string

# !! You CANNOT SET characters that way
PS> $var[0] = 'F'
InvalidOperation: Unable to index into an object of type "System.String".
```